# how to print something in avr

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, spi

I'm working on an AVR to learn. I have a question I want to print some thing but the `printf()` `printf_P()` nothing printing anything.

```
uint8_t SPI0_exchangeData(uint8_t data)
{
    
    SPI0.DATA = data;
    while (!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm))  /* waits until data is exchanged*/
    {
        printf_P("transferring0");
        printf("transferring")
    }

    return SPI0.DATA;
}
```

Comment: Where are you expecting things to be printed?

Comment: in while loop i want to print wait it's transferring and after that it show me transferring done

Comment: I mean, where are you expecting the output to be written? To what device? to what terminal? To what display?

Comment: to the console. on pc

Comment: How is your AVR board connected to the PC? How is that connection configured? Are you running some kind or program to receive the output written over the AVR-toPC connection?

Comment: my avr is connected normally. second on the pins it's connected to IKA Logic. which converts my output to graph.

Comment: @Studyonly you use MPLAB as your IDE?

Comment: @Studyonly if you use MPLAB and XC8 have a look at the instructions on the following page about how to make printf working over any hardware output.
https://microchipdeveloper.com/xc8:console-printing

Comment: IDE is Microchip Studio

Comment: printf() is a generally massive function with all the dependencies required.  something very undesireable for an mcu, certainly something as resource limited as an avr.  you can easily create your own printing functions to print debug or whatever information out (not using C librarie calls).  if you feel the need for floating point for example though you are going to explode the size of your binary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The Data Visualizer Microchip is able to receive data in ascii format, so this example assumes you use this. It is possible to use the one mentioned in the example, or the one provided in either MPLAB or Studio.

I found an example for you with the avr128da48 that shows you how to accomplish printing text over USART to the Data Visualizer terminal.

[Hello World Over USART](https://github.com/microchip-pic-avr-examples/avr128da48-usart-example)

- Remember to set the BAUD rate to the same speed on both USART and Data Visualizer
- Happy printing

[image: Hello World over USART]